# AJAX pass 2 variables to .php file

Tags: ajax

I need to pass the variables `uid` and `siteAurl` with AJAX. How do I do it?

You can see me doing it wrong here:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","insert/insert-badge.php?user="uid"&site="+siteAurl,true);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","insert/insert-badge.php?user=" + uid + "&site=" + siteAurl, true);
```

The variables `uid` and `siteAurl` should be encoded with `encodeURIComponent()` before they are used in the above URL.